# Script error, not getting the right output

Tags: bash

Below is my script, I am not getting the right output, I am typing alice I am getting bob as output, but when i am typing bob I should get alice as output, but i am getting bob as output. Kindly let me know what's the error in my script

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your name"
read a
if [ $a==alice ];
then
echo "bob"
elif [ $a==bob ];
then
echo "alice"
else
echo "STDERR"
fi
```

Comment: you need spaces around `==`. `if [ $a == 'alice' ]`

Answer (score 2):

Wrong syntax, should be:

```
[[ $a == alice ]]
```

Check: http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html

Comment: Wrong syntax, should be `[[ $a == alice ]]` if the `[[` operator is used, otherwise `[ "$a" = alice ]` or `test "$a" = alice`

Answer (score 1):

You should put spaces around your `==` operator, so that it's a three-argument form of `[`.

Without the spaces, it's using the *one-argument* form which gives true if the string length is non-zero (as it is with the string `bob==alice`).

Answer (score 0):

Spaces are required surrounding your `==` expression. When using the `[` test operator or using the keyword `test`, you will want to use the `=` for posix compliance and portability:

```
[ "$a" = alice ]  # remember to quote your variable when comparing strings
```

While `==` is **permissive** with `[` or `test`, you will lose portability. Alternatively, if you are using `[[` operator, then `==` is correct:

```
[[ "$a" == alice ]] # quoting is not required, but is good practice.
```